# Inno Setup 6.2.1 web Download failing

Tags: download, inno-setup, pascalscript

Environment: Inno Setup 6.2.1, Windows 7 (same problem on Win 10)

I’m using almost identical script as the dev’s example code (which worked.) For some reason my script appears to fail to download.

Error:
The source file "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MBBKM.tmp\version.txt" does not exist.

I tried changing download location from temp directly to userappdata but equivalent error. I also tried removing the postinstall code but no difference.

Really only difference I can see between my code and the code example is the url. (Sourceforge recently changed to https, but project received temporary http rollback.) Up to 3 files are intended to be downloaded & all three are able to download using Inno 5 with a 3rd party downloader plug-in. I am unable to obtain a single download with the inno 6 script using same url.

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=lowest

[Files]
Source: "{tmp}\version";  DestDir: "{userappdata}\wire"; Flags: external ignoreversion; Components: connect
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
DownloadPage: TDownloadWizardPage;

function OnDownloadProgress(const Url, FileName: String; const     Progress, ProgressMax: Int64): Boolean;
begin
  if Progress = ProgressMax then
Log(Format('Successfully downloaded file to {tmp}: %s', [FileName]));
  Result := True;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  DownloadPage := CreateDownloadPage(SetupMessage(msgWizardPreparing), SetupMessage(msgPreparingDesc), @OnDownloadProgress);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpReady then begin
    DownloadPage.Clear
    DownloadPage.Add('http://yyy.sourceforge.net/SecurityUpdates/version', 'version.txt', '');
    DownloadPage.Show;
    try
      try
        DownloadPage.Download; // This downloads the files to {tmp}
        Result := True;
      except
        SuppressibleMsgBox(AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage), mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    finally
      DownloadPage.Hide;
    end;
  end else
    Result := True;
end;
```

Edited url & filename

EDIT Dec 2022: QUESTION:
Having problems when Components section added. Compiles ok, but unable to locate temporary file problem during test runs. What extra needs to be done when this download code is used for a components installer?

Components and Files section set up as per normal. File section includes components reference, {tmp} and external flag.
I'm tending to think a component reference needs to be added to the download code but attempts have failed to compile.

Comment: I had a components section that was causing problems. Once removed it works fine.  I had tried the 2nd parameter previously but had not worked until now.

Comment: I suggest you start a new question with [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Url of the file to download is incorrect. Simply check it in browser, I get error 404:

[image: browser]

Comment: You are right. No file ext for the version file and it's reverted temporarily to http. http://wireshare.sourceforge.net/WSSecurityUpdates/version  But up to 3 files are intended to be downloaded & all three are able to download using Inno 5 with a downloader plug-in. I am unable to get a single download with this script.